# Email button not showing in Activity History related list on Case Lightning Page layout

Tags: lightning, email, lightning-experience, case, page-layout

I have added the Email button to the Classic Case Page layout in the Salesforce Mobile and Lightning Experience Actions section.
I have also added the Activity History related List to the corresponding Case Lightning Page, but the Email button is not visible for some reason.
[image]

I have been able to do this on both the Lead and Contact Lightning Page Layouts successfully but I can't figure out why it's not working on the Case Lightning page.

Comment: can you check the https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000331369&type=1 ?? let me know this helps.

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: I had already done some googling and found that article but its just making sure that the email deliverability is set correctly which it is so, no that didn't resolve it.